# Use CA certificate for AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Can I use CA certificate in the origin and cloudfront default certificate in Cloudfront? Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

yes this should work, you can even put no ssl between your origin and cloudfront, and activate ssl between the end users and cloudfront. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html